# Why this exception is thrown when I try to use an iterator on this list?

Tags: java, list, iterator, java-collections-api

I have a collection of this type:

```
List<com.liferay.portal.model.Role> ruoli
ruoli = currentUser.getRoles();
```

that contains 3 elements (I see it using the debugger), each **Role** object have a **name** field and the 3 objects into the previos list have the following names: **Administrator**, **Power User** and **User**.

So I am trying to use an **iterator** to iterate on this list and print the values of the name field of these 3 objects contained into the **ruoli** list, so I do in this way:

```
Iterator<Role> iteratorUserRoles = ruoli.iterator();

while (iteratorUserRoles.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(iteratorUserRoles.next().getName());
    iteratorUserRoles.next();
}
```

The problem is that it don't show

but in the stacktrace I obtain:

```
**Administrator**
**Power User**
**User**
```

as I expect but I obtain this message:

```
**Administrator**
**User**
```

and then it throws this exception:

2015-01-26 10:20:13,071 [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] ERROR commons.CommonsLogger.error(38) - Could not execute action
java.util.NoSuchElementException

It seems that the exception is thrown when it try to perform this operation:

```
iteratorUserRoles.next();
```

Why? What could be the problem? What am I mising? How can I fix this issue and correctly iterate on all the objects into my list?

Tnx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are advancing the iterator twice in each iteration.

```
while (iteratorUserRoles.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(iteratorUserRoles.next().getName());
    //iteratorUserRoles.next(); remove this
}
```

If the iterator has one remaining element and you call `iteratorUserRoles.next()` twice, you'll get an exception.

Answer (score 1):

`Iterator#next()` is not a getter. It advances the pointer and returns the element at the new position.

Assign the value returned to a variable if you need to touch it twice:

```
Iterator<Role> iteratorUserRoles = ruoli.iterator();

while (iteratorUserRoles.hasNext()) {
    Role role = iteratorUserRoles.next();
    System.out.println(role.getName());
    // do something else with role
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are calling iterator.next() two times in while cycle. That's why you get exception (and why you miss second element)

However I would recommend you not to access iterator in this way. Use its mechanics in for loop like this.

```
for (com.liferay.portal.model.Role role : ruoli){
    System.out.println(role.getName());
}
```